# JS: "Uncaught TypeError: Type error" when trying to use putImageData

Tags: javascript

I am trying to program a very simple image manipulator. My first function is to greyscale the image.

The HTML:

```
<body onload="loadImage()">
<div id="canvascontainer">
      <h1>WTSP - Way Too Simple Photoshop</h1>
      <canvas id="wtspcanvas">
        Sorry, selbst für das zu simple Photoshop ist dein Browser zu simpel. <!-- Fallback -->
      </canvas>

      <p><input type="button" value="In Graustufen konvertieren" onclick="greyScale()" /></p>
 </div>
```

The JS:

```
    function loadImage() {
    _canvas  = document.getElementById("wtspcanvas");       // Canvas anwählen
    var bildObj = new Image();                                  // Bildobjekt anlegen

    bildObj.onload = function() {
        showImage(bildObj, _canvas);                                // Bild und Canvas an showImage weitergeben
    };
    bildObj.src  = "img/wtsp.png";
    return bildObj;
}

function showImage(bildObj, canvas) {
    _canvasWidth  = bildObj.naturalWidth;               // Höhe und Breite des Bildes holen
    _canvasHeight = bildObj.naturalHeight;              // In Variable speichern für später

    canvas.width  = _canvasWidth;                           // Höhe und Breite des Canvas entsprechend setzen
    canvas.height = _canvasHeight;

    var context = _canvas.getContext("2d");                     // 2-dimensionalen Kontext setzen, global
    context.drawImage(bildObj, 0, 0);                       // Bild in der oberen linken Ecke zeichnen

    _pixel = context.getImageData(0, 0, _canvasWidth, _canvasHeight);   // Bilddaten in globaler Variable speichern
}

function greyScale() {
    var context = _canvas.getContext("2d");
    var bildDaten = context.getImageData(0, 0, _canvasWidth, _canvasHeight);
    for(var i = 0; i < bildDaten.length; i += 4) {
        bildDaten.data[i] = bildDaten.data[i]*0.299;
        bildDaten.data[i + 1] = bildDaten.data[i + 1]*0.587;
        bildDaten.data[i + 2] = bildDaten.data[i + 2]*0.114;
        // bildDaten.data[i + 3] = 1; 
    }
    context.putImageData(bildDaten.data, 0, 0, _canvasWidth, _canvasHeight);
}
```

The error occurs in the last line of greyScale. Chrome's JS console spits out:

```
[Error] TypeError: Type error
    greyScale (manipulator.js, line 28)
    onclick (index.html, line 21)
```

I am by no means a JS-expert, so my code might not be the cleanest. Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to get rid of the error and make the function work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.putImageData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#putImageData%28%29) expects an [`ImageData`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/2dcontext/html5_canvas/Overview.html#imagedata) object as the first parameter - as obtained by [`.getImageData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#getImageData%28%29)

So you have to change the last line from

```
context.putImageData(bildDaten.data, 0, 0, _canvasWidth, _canvasHeight);
```

to

```
context.putImageData(bildDaten, 0, 0, _canvasWidth, _canvasHeight);
```

Comment: This at least gets rid of the error. However after clicking the button, the canvas doesn't change at all. Is there another step required to actually show the newly calculated pixels?

Comment: Alright, I got it. `bildDaten.length` was an undefined value. Replaced it with `_canvasWidth*_canvasHeight*4`

Comment: or `bildDaten.data.length`

Comment: The Mozilla documentation has it incorrect. Thanks!